# my cron job_code not getting inserted into cron_schedule table

Tags: cron, magento-1.7

What i already tried are:

1. scheduler extension which is clearly showing me that job in list view. Also when i try to run job manually it works but it doesn't come automatically on table all other job shows up fine. I am struggling since so many days .Please help.

Comment: provide more information about your system and scenario. While I've limited knowledge in this very case , still I feel you'll need to provide more input.

Comment: i wanted to understand the place where magento decide to put cron job into cron_schedule table because i wanted to know when all my xml etc are correct why they never get inserted into table.They work fine when i try running it mannually so i know that functionally also they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I usually manage my cronjobs via SSH. From there, I use the following commands:

> sudo crontab -e
>
> This should bring up your cronjobs. To add cronjobs, simply start typing.
>
> After you are done, hit the "ESC" key and type ":x" then hit the "Enter" key
>
> To make sure that your cronjobss don't have any errors, type "sudo crontab -l"

Hopefully this helps